# What about atomic_flag.wait/notify_one in gcc and clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20

I can not find any new c++20 features of std::atomic_flag (Proposal P0995R1)

I looked in gcc status table but did not found anything about it
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Then i tried compile code below on gcc and clang compilers, but this code compiles only on trunk branch of gcc and clang

```
#include <atomic>
#include  <thread>

int main()
{
    std::atomic_flag f;

    std::thread t([&] 
    {
        f.wait(false);
        std::cout << "gggg" << std::endl;
    });
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
    f.test_and_set();
    f.notify_all();

    t.join();

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Does anyone know about implementation status of this features?

Comment: P0995R1 proposal was integrated into [P1135R6](http://wg21.link/p1135r6), and here is [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) / [libcxx](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/Cxx2aStatus.html) status page.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of latest feature heavily depends on the compiler.
Use boost::atomic_flag. it is original and compiler/os independent